# How to schedule copies on transfer queue with a semaphore?

Tags: c++, vulkan

I am aiming to use `vkCmdCopyBuffer` with a transfer queue that is signaled via semaphore from a compute <strike>shader</strike> queue. The compute shader is running on a graphics queue and is intended to signal the transfer queue to copy to host and also to signal the render. My goal is to have the copy to host done on a different queue to the graphics queue.

I am currently getting the error message:

> VULKAN> ERROR(violation): Validation Error: [ UNASSIGNED-CoreValidation-DrawState-QueueForwardProgress ] Object 0: handle = 0x301e6c0000000022, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_SEMAPHORE; Object 1: handle = 0x21d51d0ac80, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_QUEUE; Object 2: handle = 0x21d51d0ac80, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_QUEUE; | MessageID = 0xe825f293 | vkQueueSubmit(): pSubmits[0].pSignalSemaphores[1] is signaling VkQueue 0x21d51d0ac80[] (VkSemaphore 0x301e6c0000000022[]) that was previously signaled by VkQueue 0x21d51d0ac80[] but has not since been waited on by any queue.

The compute shader is submit with:

```
void Renderer::runCompute()
{
    VkSemaphore waitSemaphores[]      = { mComputeReadySemaphore };
    VkSemaphore signalSemaphores[]    = { mComputeFinishedSemaphoreGraphics, mComputeFinishedSemaphoreTransfer };
    VkPipelineStageFlags waitStages[] = { VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COMPUTE_SHADER_BIT };

    VkSubmitInfo submitInfo{};
    submitInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_SUBMIT_INFO;

    if (mHasDispatchedCompute) [[likely]]
    {
        submitInfo.waitSemaphoreCount = ARR_LEN(waitSemaphores);
        submitInfo.pWaitSemaphores    = waitSemaphores;
        submitInfo.pWaitDstStageMask  = waitStages;
    }
    else
    {
        mHasDispatchedCompute = true;
    }

    submitInfo.signalSemaphoreCount = ARR_LEN(signalSemaphores);
    submitInfo.pSignalSemaphores    = signalSemaphores;
    submitInfo.commandBufferCount   = 1;
    submitInfo.pCommandBuffers      = &mComputeCommandBuffer;

    if (vkQueueSubmit(mpGraphicsQueue, 1, &submitInfo, VK_NULL_HANDLE) != VK_SUCCESS)
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to submit command buffer!");
}
```

And the transfer queue is submit with:

```
void Renderer::runTransfer()
{
    VkSemaphore waitSemaphores[]      = { mComputeFinishedSemaphoreTransfer };
    VkPipelineStageFlags waitStages[] = { VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_ALL_COMMANDS_BIT };

    VkSubmitInfo submitInfo{};
    submitInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_SUBMIT_INFO;

    if (mHasDispatchedTransfer) [[likely]]
    {
        submitInfo.waitSemaphoreCount = ARR_LEN(waitSemaphores);
        submitInfo.pWaitSemaphores    = waitSemaphores;
        submitInfo.pWaitDstStageMask  = waitStages;
    }
    else
    {
        mHasDispatchedTransfer = true;
    }

    submitInfo.commandBufferCount   = 1;
    submitInfo.pCommandBuffers      = &mTransferCommandBuffer;

    if (vkQueueSubmit(mpTransferQueue, 1, &submitInfo, mTransferReadFence) != VK_SUCCESS)
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to submit command buffer!");
}
```

And called here:

```
    constexpr uint32_t SINGLE_FRAME_RENDERING = 0;

    vkWaitForFences(mpLogicDevice, 1, &mTransferReadFence, VK_TRUE, UINT64_MAX);
    updateFrame(SINGLE_FRAME_RENDERING);
    vkResetFences(mpLogicDevice, 1, &mTransferReadFence);

    runCompute();
    runTransfer();

    auto imageIndex = prepareFrame();

    // Submit the command buffer
    VkSubmitInfo submitInfo{};
    submitInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_SUBMIT_INFO;

    VkSemaphore waitSemaphores[]      = { mImageAvailableSemaphores[SINGLE_FRAME_RENDERING], mComputeFinishedSemaphoreGraphics };
    VkPipelineStageFlags waitStages[] = { VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT, VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_FRAGMENT_SHADER_BIT };
    submitInfo.waitSemaphoreCount     = ARR_LEN(waitSemaphores);
    submitInfo.pWaitSemaphores        = waitSemaphores;
    submitInfo.pWaitDstStageMask      = waitStages;
    submitInfo.commandBufferCount     = 1;
    submitInfo.pCommandBuffers        = &mGraphicsCommandBuffers[createCommandBuffersOnce() ? imageIndex : SINGLE_FRAME_RENDERING];
    VkSemaphore signalSemaphores[]    = { mRenderFinishedSemaphores[SINGLE_FRAME_RENDERING], mComputeReadySemaphore };
    submitInfo.signalSemaphoreCount   = ARR_LEN(signalSemaphores);
    submitInfo.pSignalSemaphores      = signalSemaphores;

    if (vkQueueSubmit(mpGraphicsQueue, 1, &submitInfo, mInFlightFences[SINGLE_FRAME_RENDERING]) != VK_SUCCESS)
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to submit draw command buffer!");

    submitFrame(signalSemaphores, imageIndex);
```

Where `updateFrame()` is a host manipulation of the buffer, `prepareFrame()` is swap chain image acquisition and `submitFrame()` calls `vkQueuePresentKHR()`.

Comment: "*with a transfer queue that is signaled via semaphore from a compute shader.*" No, you're trying to have a compute *queue* signal a transfer queue. A compute *shader* cannot signal anything.

Comment: Ah sorry, I do understand I just wrote it incorrectly. Does what I am trying to here make sense or are there better ways to go about it?

Comment: What is the state of `mHasDispatchedTransfer`? If it is ever false, then the semaphore is never unsignaled.

Comment: Additionally, `runCompute` signals `ComputeFinishedSemaphoreTransfer`, but `runTransfer` waits on some different semaphore `mComputeFinishedSemaphoreTransfer`.

Comment: Yeah that was it, I had `mHasDispatchedTransfer` as false! Thank you very much for spotting that. That fix has cleared the error, but the overall performance per frame appears to be worse than just doing the copy in the compute queue (versus this example which uses a dedicated transfer queue). Is that expected?

Comment: @phoenixinwater Transfers within the GPU should be done on the same queue for performance reasons. Transfers between GPU and host should be done on dedicated transfer (DMA) queue **asynchronously**, so GPU is freed to do other work.

Comment: @krOoze thank you, I need the host to manipulate the data per frame, does that mean I will receive no benefit using a dedicated transfer queue in this use case? And the main benefit would be for loading data that is not frame-dependent?

Comment: @phoenixinwater Not sure. Can be frame dependent, just not serialized with all the other work. Additionally some vendors offer specific memory type for this case that doesn't need transfers. You would be better served to formulating your question with as much detail as you can offer and post it as a Question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if(mHasDispatchedTransfer)` may remove the wait on the semaphore `mComputeFinishedSemaphoreTransfer`, but the semaphore is unconditionally signaled in `runCompute()`. That will lead to the semaphore being signaled repeatedly without no wait inbetween if `mHasDispatchedTransfer` is `false`.